# Would with present tense in if clause

Tags: would-rather

I m seeing a person for the first time and he tells me " I am from police."

Is it okay to use "how would I know that you are from police?" In my reply or should I use "how would I know that you were from police?"

Comment: Both are correct. How would .........is more polite than how will ..........

Comment: The question is not about being polite, the question raises a doubt there whether he is from police or not.

Answer (score 1):

You would say **that you are**, because you're talking about the present, not the past.

And it would be from **the** police.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about using *would* in present tenses, as the title suggests, I can say that:

> We can use **would** [to give an opinion when we are not sure or when we want to be polite.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-or-would)

Therefore, I think there is no problem in using *would* in present tenses.

By the way, I think you can also reply:

> How should I know that you are from the police?

Comment: My question is should I use "are" or "were"? If your answer is are, how it will be right according to the rules of conditional sentence?

Comment: @Joann I arranged the answer based on your title. However, I edit the answer to include it